# ¿Por qué no recibo solamente el texto del Item? (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Puedo enviar al *item* el texto que escribo en mi `EditText` a la 'database' de *Firebase* y funciona perfectamente, pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de recibir el texto en mi `TextView`.

Si escribo por ejemplo:

"**hola**", recibo lo siguiente en mi `TextView` "DataSnapshot {key = item, value = **hola**}" ¿Por qué no recibo solo "**hola**"?

Este es mi código:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receptor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receptor);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child(FIREBASE_CHILD);

        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    // recibo en mi textview
                    receptor.setText(snapshot.toString());
                    Log.e(getLocalClassName(), snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    // envio a firebase

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void writeToFirebase() {
        firebase.setValue(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con `snapshot.getValue().toString()` en vez de poner `snapshot.toString()`?

Comment: Vaya despiste! Efectivamente ese era mi error, ponlo en una respuesta y la marco como solución, gracias ! @cnbandicoot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando convertir un objeto `DataSnapshot` a `String`, es por ello que te devuelve el objeto con sus propiedades en forma de `String`. Para coger el valor simplemente usa `getValue()`:

```
receptor.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
```

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado :) !